# Why am I getting duplicate errors in my obj/Release/net6.0 folder after building and deploying Azure function in VS Code

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

My Azure function works, I can debug it, and deploy it no problem. But when I deploy it and it gets built into the release folder I see errors in the obj -> Release/net6.0 folder.
FYI - I deploy by using the Azure extension and in the Azure workspace panel I click on deploy, then choose my resource group and it runs on it's own and deploys no problem.

I'm wondering if it has something to do with the name I gave my project
"Functions" ?

I'll post what I see below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is my .csproj file for the Azure function project

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Core\Core.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Infrastructure\Infrastructure.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: could you please provide your `.csproj` file code?

Comment: I'll post my .csproj file for the Azure function project. If you want another file let me know.

Comment: Why are you looking at the release folder in the first place? Your app is working, the error is most likely just an IDE issue because VSCode is confused by its content. Does the error appear even if you don't explicitly open the file?

Comment: I have tested basic Azure Function .net core 6 http trigger deploying to Azure, it created release folder and doesn't get any errors in that folder - https://i.imgur.com/KhOidAs.png

Comment: could you try including this bit of code in .csproj file > under property group > `<GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>` and deploy > check

Comment: Hello @user1186050, Any update on the issue?

Comment: no, haven't gotten any resolution on this yet.

Comment: Could you please try few things like 1) Delete `bin` & `Obj` folder from the project/solution and rebuild > deploy  2) Run VSCode as an administrator 3) try setting `generateassembly - false` above code bit in `.csproj` file under property group and still if you're getting the issues, could you please provide your functionality what you are doing on the function code so that we will try the same functionality from my side and will check!

Comment: One basic test, have you checked the function app in the portal belongs to .NET Core 6, Function Runtime Version is 4 in the Azure Portal > Function App > Configuration > Application Settings, General Settings

Comment: @user1186050 any update to the issue? and have you changed the folder structure before deploying the project?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar/related problem a week ago (if you ask me to recall it, I'd need to go through heaps of my screenshots). I was able to deploy my Azure function via GitHub but it wouldn't work and I made satisfactory progress by changing (in the Azure Portal) the value of Configuration | Function Runtime Settings | Runtime Version to the value: ~4. However, just today, the portal is warning me to go back to the value: ~3. So, it is just something you might want to try and be prepared to undo.

On a loosely related topic, yesterday I started having problems with deployment again (via GitHub CI/CD). Today, in the Activity Log under a "Sync Web Apps Function Triggers" entry I **saw** the error: "Encountered an error (BadGateway) from host runtime". A few minutes later it was cleared (and it said it had run for 13 minutes). Now, I'd been in the portal about 15 minutes, so that might have fixed today's issue  -- I figured the job was still in the queue and today it was able to pick it up and work it through. By visiting the function in the portal, it must have helped initialize it somehow. Still working on this one. I'll try resetting the Runtime Version value back to the suggested value ~3.

Good luck with your issue. Cheers, Henk.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried replicating your setup (e.g. "Functions" name) on a Mac with Visual Studio details bellow, without any issues however. If you've used any preview version of VS or even Azure Function Extensions, then I suggest you re-create a new project and import your artifacts.

My setup is the following:

- Release ID: 1703001972
- Git revision: 8eb3c1bb0f14a8e54ee7c227c7047c46cff6ee8c. Build date: 2022-07-12 19:09:28+00
- Build branch: release-17.3
- Running on .NET 6.0.5 (64-bit)
- Operating System: Mac OS X 12.4.0
- Darwin 21.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.5.0

Comment: OP is using VS Code, not the Visual Studio.